# Why willDisplayCell is not called the second time

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a view controller with a table. When a cell is created and presented the first time, the following functions are called in the order (in addition to view controller functions):

```
....
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)

func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? 

optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
....
```

When I exit the screen an, the following functions were called.

```
....
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)

func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
....
```

But why `willDisplaycell` was not called between `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`?

The logs are:

```
viewWillAppear
cellForRowAtIndexPath: 0 
willDisplayCell: 0 
cellForRowAtIndexPath: 1 
willDisplayCell: 1 
cellForRowAtIndexPath: 2 
willDisplayCell: 2 
viewWillDisappear
viewWillAppear
viewWillDisappear
```

Instead of:

```
viewWillAppear
cellForRowAtIndexPath: 0 
willDisplayCell: 0 
cellForRowAtIndexPath: 1 
willDisplayCell: 1 
cellForRowAtIndexPath: 2 
willDisplayCell: 2 
viewWillDisappear
viewWillAppear
willDisplayCell: 0 
willDisplayCell: 1 
willDisplayCell: 2 
viewWillDisappear
```

Comment: Where do you set the datasource for your table ? If it's not in viewWillAppear then the tableview won't reload, so no call for willDisplayCell :)

Comment: @danypata I do not expect the table to reload, but the cells reaper on the screen, so I expect  willDisplayCell to be called

Comment: You didn't understand the ```willDisplayCell```. This method is called during the display phase of the UITableView when it actually display the cells. In your case, because the datasource hasn't changed and the cells are already created & displayed the tableView won't call the method again. Think about it as a flag set to "true" that is not turned to "false" when the controller is hidden.

Comment: @danypata I see. So what should I use to be notified when the cells presented on the screen again?

Comment: A simple, reloadData, in viewWillAppear will do the trick. (not 100 % sure tho) You'll have to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did eventually is checking what cells are presented in viewDidAppear. Not sure it's the best answer, so don't hesitate to add better ones.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self logVisibleSections];
}

-(void)logVisibleSections
{
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)
    {
        // Do what needs to be done with visible cells 
    }
}
```